# Element unexcpectedly hidden on some instances of Safari, always appears in Firefox, Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created an angular app the acts as "bounce" page for a social iOS application, that is in public beta.

- Users can share their profiles among each other as a link to the site.
- If the page is opened on an iOS device, and the app is installed, it opens the app using the app's URL scheme. Otherwise it redirects to the App Store.
- For all other devices, android, desktop, etc it just renders a simple information page.

**The problem:**

On one instance of Safari, two elements of the page are not rendered.

**Missing elements:**

- "Instruments" label below the profile name does not appear.
- Copyright, privacy and terms and conditions does not appear.

**On all other instances of Safari, also Chrome and Firefox, it appears correctly as follows:**

- The site is implemented using Angular + Bootstrap.

**Page source for the section with the missing instruments label is:**

```
<div ng-show="vm.loaded">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 profile-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="min-width: 300px !important;">
                    <div class="card hovercard">
                        <div class="photo-container">
                        </div>
                        <div class="useravatar">
                            <img ng-src="{{vm.profile.coverPhotoURL}}" vpr-load="vm.onImageLoaded()">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top: -10px">
                    <span class="profile-title">{{vm.titleText()}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top: 8px">
                    <span class="profile-sub-title">{{vm.instruments()}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="padding-bottom: 20px">
                    <span class="profile-genres">{{vm.genres()}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**And the footer is as follows:**

```
<footer class="vFooter hidden-xs">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-xs-6 text-center" style="height: 80px">
            <div class="vertical-center">
                <p class="copyright vertical-center" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <span class="text-nowrap">© Vampr Pty Ltd 2016 | <vpr-link-bar></vpr-link-bar></span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
   (etc, etc)
```

(some closing `<div>` tags not shown in source snippet above)

**Question:**

Without having access to the machine where the problem occurs, how can I debug and correct the issue?

I found a similar problem on another instance of Safari that seemed to be caused by AdBlock - disabling it made the elements appear correctly. However the elements in question were different once - the social media buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to have been caused, simply, by an unescaped ampersand '&' character in the HTML source. Fixing this solved the problem. I'm not sure why the issue occurred only on one particular instance of Safari out of many others.